# Split string with Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

This is what I have that's working but want it a different way.

```
System.out.print("Enter the car's Year, Make and Model: ");
String scyear =  scan.nextLine();
String scmake =  scan.nextLine();
String scmodel =  scan.nextLine();
NewCar test = new NewCar(scyear, scmake, scmodel);
```

This is what I want: user runs Java program and it asks:

```
Enter the car's Year, Make and Model:
```

I then type:

```
2011 Honda Civic
```

It will then use the spaces that I entered as a way to separate the variables to be put correctly into the constructor. It will separate them to 3 separate variables from the single 1 line string that I entered.

Answer (score 2):

```
String myCarData[]=scan.nextLine().split(" ");
NewCar test=new NewCar(myCarData[0],myCarData[1],myCarData[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Scanner.next`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) method, which retrieves the next complete token from the Scanner. Here's a snippet of the documentation:

> `public String next()`
>
> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.

This is delimited by a space by default as the method is overloaded, thus you can do this:

```
System.out.print("Enter the car's Year, Make and Model: ");
String scyear = scan.next();
String scmake = scan.next();
String scmodel = scan.next();
NewCar test = new NewCar(scyear, scmake, scmodel);
```

Given the input:

```
Enter the car's Year, Make and Model: 2011 Honda Civic
```

The `next` will essentially do:

```
Enter the car's Year, Make and Model: 2011 Honda Civic
                                      ^^^^ ^^^^^ ^^^^^
```

It will get the *next* token from input. Calling `next` will get you 2011, again will give you Honda, and finally will give you Civic. Alternatively, you can split the line into an array, and retrieve using subscription though it may be slower.

Comment: this is your answer ken.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `scan.nextLine()`, use `scan.next()`

```
   System.out.print("Enter the car's Year, Make and Model: ");
    String scyear =  scan.next();
    String scmake =  scan.next();
    String scmodel =  scan.next();
```

The next three things you enter (seperated by a space) will be what is automatically assigned to `scyear`, `scmake` and `scmodel`. It is very annoying in most cases, but in this case you can use it to your favor. It is also useful when entering X,Y coordinates and latitude/longitude.